# Catch PostgreSQL exception and change column value

Tags: json, postgresql, exception

I have a column called `metadata` which has format `TEXT` but contains stuff that's usually a JSON. I want to select a certain value in it (`metadata :: JSON -> 'register' ->> 'date'` for instance) but if the JSON is badly formatted or if the field doesn't exist I get an error. Can I make that column just return a `NULL` value when it would get an error instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a stored procedure that tries to cast to json and returns null of failure. Something like this:

```
create function to_json(t text) returns json as $$
begin
  return t::json;
exception when invalid_text_representation then
  return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

and then use `to_json(metadata) -> 'register' ->> 'date'`.

Comment: Works fine but I would avoid creating a function named as existing built in PostgreSQL functions https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE

Comment: is such a `to_json` function that returns `NULL` on error instead of throwing still not built into psql as of 2024?